# ZF2 overwriting my error handler?

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2

I think ZF2 appears to be overwriting my custom error handler.

In my initialisation, I'm setting the database, then doing the follow.

```
$errorHandling = new catalina\ErrorHandler($database);
set_error_handler(
    array($errorHandling, 'userErrorHandler')
);


set_exception_handler(
    array($errorHandling, 'userExceptionHandler')
);

/**
 * Configure the session management
 */

$sessionOptions         = new DbTableGatewayOptions();
$sessionTableGateway    = new TableGateway('session', $database);
$saveHandler            = new DbTableGateway($sessionTableGateway, $sessionOptions);
$sessionManager         = new SessionManager(NULL, NULL, $saveHandler);

/**
 * Start the session
 */
$sessionManager->start();
```

It would appear that as soon as I start the session, my custom error handling is not obeyed. Any ideas what's not good?

Even setting it after the session has started doesn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Perhaps you should grep the ZF2 codebase for `set_exception_handler`?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't that - for some reason, a global variable was killing it - god I hate globals :/